# Cordova Splashscreen iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus not showing

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen, cordova-plugins

I updated the cordova splashscreen plugin to properly show i6 and i6 Plus splash images but I can't  get it working.

When the app starts in the console appears a message saying that does not found the LaunchImage-667h if the device is an iPhone6 and LaunchImage-736h if is an iPhone 6 Plus but I have all the splashscreen images in its respective sizes properly configured in the Image Asset catalog

Is there an extra config to get it working?

Comment: Are you using Xcode or Phonegap build?

Comment: Did you try this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26283372/phonegap-and-iphone-6-plus-splash-screen-issue

Comment: @xmarston I have this same issue but the solution from NijilNair doesn't work for me. Any suggestion? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with version 2.0.0 and was able to resolve it by upgrading to version 3.2.0.