# Ionic - (ios only) still shows the circle loading icon from splash in the background of the apps first viewable template and is unresponsive

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I've been having issues after the splashscreen launches only on ios (using emulator and device), I've seen a lot on this issue and still cannot seem to fix my issue on ios where the circle loading icon stays in the center of the screen after the splash goes away and my apps first page is unresponsive (with the loading circle icon still there). I've tried removing the `plugins` & `platforms` and adding them back, dragging the old project into a new one and have checkout the following and no luck.

- [Cordova Splashscreen iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27974758/cordova-splashscreen-iphone-6-and-iphone-6-plus-not-showing)
- [PhoneGap and iPhone 6 Plus splash screen issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26283372/phonegap-and-iphone-6-plus-splash-screen-issue)
- https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/important-all-ionic-users-please-update-your-keyboard-plugin/46889/2

Im using the default keyboard settings:

```
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
       cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
       cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
       StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
```

My system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.1.0 (cordova-lib@undefined)
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
Ionic Version: 1.2.4
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.0
ios-deploy version: 1.8.5 
ios-sim version: 5.0.6 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v5.7.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3 Build version 7D175
```

my plugins:

```
cordova-plugin-actionsheet 2.2.2 "ActionSheet"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.2 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.7.0 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.3.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 2.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.0.1 "Keyboard"
```

When I run `ionic run ios --device` or `emulate` it will more often then not say `Build Successful` in the log and not load on the device or emulator.

In addition and will sometime get

```
WARN: hideKeyboardAccessoryBar has been removed until a method is found that doesn't get rejected from the App Store.
```

in the xcode log, however, as I've stated I have updated the plugin as noted in https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/important-all-ionic-users-please-update-your-keyboard-plugin/46889/2

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App?
Are you waiting for the `deviceready` event? Are you setting the compiler version? Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem today!

In my case I was hiding the splashscreen with 
`navigator.splashscreen.hide();`

It works in the past for both iOS and Android. But now it doesn't works for iOS and until now I can't find why this is happening.

Comment: As this isn't a solution this may be better suited as a comment. I worked around it by putting my www folder in a older version when I didn't have this issue

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't have enough reputation to comment on your question! I can delete it after.
So your problem has nothing to to with splashscreen, right?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your config.xml file

```
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
```