# iPhone 6 splash screen resized after few second

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

The splash screen appear normal (fit) at first and then after 2 seconds or so it resized / stretched onto right side off the screen

I'm developing iOS app using phonegap only (no xCode)

the iPhone 6 I use for testing is using iOS 9.2.1

here's config.xml :

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.polri.polisiku" version="1.0.0">
    <name>PolisiKu</name>
    <description>PolisiKu adalah aplikasi pencari pos polisi terdekat dari posisi user.</description>
    <author href="http://polri.go.id" email="mabes@polri.go.id">Divti Polri</author>
    <content src="index.html"/>

    <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
    <preference name="target-device" value="handset"/>
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.2.1" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" source="pgb" spec="0.2.12" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" source="pgb" spec="0.3.6" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" source="pgb" spec="0.2.13" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" source="pgb" spec="0.2.16" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" source="pgb" spec="0.3.0" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" source="pgb" spec="0.2.11" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" source="pgb" spec="0.3.11" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" source="pgb" spec="0.3.0" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" source="pgb" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" source="pgb" spec="0.5.0" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" source="pgb" spec="0.3.12" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" source="pgb" spec="0.3.4" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" source="pgb" spec="0.6.0" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" source="pgb" spec="0.2.16" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" source="pgb" spec="0.3.6" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" source="pgb" spec="0.2.15" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" source="pgb" spec="1.0.0" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.statusbar" source="pgb" spec="0.1.4" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" source="pgb" spec="0.3.13" />

    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <splash src="splash.png" />

    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>

    <splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape.png" platform="ios" width="480" height="320" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-2x.png" platform="ios" width="960" height="640" />

    <!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-568h-2x.png" platform="ios" width="1136" height="640" />

    <!-- iPhone 6 -->
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-667h@2x~iphone.png" platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-667h@2x~iphone.png" platform="ios" width="1334" height="750" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-736h@3x~iphone.png" platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h@3x~iphone.png" platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242" />

    <!-- iPad -->
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />

    <!-- Retina iPad -->
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />

    <access origin="*"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
    <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
    </platform>
</widget>
```

the question is similar with [PhoneGap and iPhone 6 Plus splash screen issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26283372/phonegap-and-iphone-6-plus-splash-screen-issue/) but i've tried all answer and nothing work, and they haven't marked an accepted answer.

thanks in advance and sorry for bad english

Comment: have you updated your `splash screen plugin`?

Comment: also, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26807884/3288182)

Comment: @Scar my splash screen is latest version 1.0.0 . tried your link, it resulted only white blank splash screen :(

Comment: [look at this](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/app-auto-scaling-on-iphone-6-and-6-screens)

Comment: @Scar yes read that before posting the question. as you can see i already apply the answer there which is include all 14 splash screen and upgrade splash screen plugin to latest version. still not working

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App? Are you using the Desktop App? What is your target platform and their target versions: Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? -- Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Answer (score 0):

The splash screen is not resizing, it moves down because of the statusbar.

So, if you have enabled the statusbar the images have to be 20px shorter and for @2x 40px.

Comment: i don't think that's the problem because it moves right not down. nevertheless, i tried your advice and no change

Answer (score 0):

You are using the latest plugin on pgb (1.0.0), but that is too old ang pgb plugins are deprecated, you have to install latest version of the plugin from NPM (3.2.1)

Change

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" source="pgb" spec="1.0.0" />
```

to

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen"/>
```